# What is the best way to say "online now" in Japanese?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to say "my friends are online now" or "I'm online right now".

So far, I have considered:

- ネットでいます。
- オンラインです。

For instance:

> 私は今ネットでいます。
>
> 友達はオンラインです。

However, I feel I'm missing something here. Is there any idiomatic expression I'm not aware of, or I am just overthinking it?

Answer (score 5):

オンラインです is perfectly correct and natural. On the other hand, ネットでいます is ungrammatical. Remember that the particle you use with いる/ある is に, not で. ネットにいます is correct, but this is much less idiomatic than オンラインです.

And note that:

- 'Friend' in contexts related to SNS or gaming is typically translated as フレンド rather than 友達.
- Please consider whether what you actually want is a UI indicator like "Friends: Online" or a *full* sentence like "Your friends are online." If you want the former, "フレンド: オンライン" will suffice, and a full sentence containing です would be redundant.

Comment: thank you so much~!

Answer (score 3):

Naruto answered pretty well, I just thought I'd add that on social media and whatnot it usually says 「オンライン中」to say they a user is currently online. I'm not sure how great this works in a full sentence, but it's good to be aware of.